# How do I open the "My Documents" and "My Computer" folders from C#?

Tags: c#, shortcut

I have used two GUIDs to open the folders *My Computer* and *My Documents*.

```
Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}");
Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "::{450d8fba-ad25-11d0-98a8-0800361b1103}");
```

But it opens Internet Explorer and then opens the folders *My Computer* and *My Documents*.

Comment: You should wrap this guids into consts with meaningful names. This can save a lot time for you and/or your colleagues.

Comment: @arbiter that's a very good suggestion, it'd make it much more friendly to any developers maintaining the code.

Comment: Please revoke the answer with the hard coded guids.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better still would be to skip `explorer` entirely and just "start" the GUIDs directly:

`Process.Start("::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}");`...

Comment: hard-core!
This will provide lots of fun for the junior developer who'll have to debug through this kind of code 5 years from now :)

Comment: For a complete reference of these magic guids, check out the KnownFolderId documentation on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/shell/knownfolderid

Answer (score 41):

Using those hard coded Guid values doesn't look like the best way of achieving this.

You could use the [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) function to get the path of any of the system special folders.  It accepts an [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enum.

This way it'd be more robust, because you wouldn't have any "magic" hardcoded values.

Here's how you'd use it:

```
//get the folder paths
string myComputerPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
string myDocumentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
//open explorer and point it at the paths
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer", myComputerPath);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer", myDocumentsPath);
```

**Important note for Windows 7 users**

It seems that trying to use this code to open My Computer on Windows 7 incorrectly results in the Libraries folder being opened instead.  This is because the default behaviour of running explorer with an empty path has changed in Windows 7.

I've filed the following bug report over at connect, go and give it an upvote if you think that this is important!

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/757291/environment-getfolderpath-not-working-correctly-in-windows-7#details

*(Thanks to JeremyK in the comments for pointing this out)*

Comment: If I try this on Windows 7 it does not open My Computer by instead the library folder which is not intended

Comment: @JeremyK it seems that My Computer returns an empty path, and this opens "Libraries" in Windows 7 instead of "My Computer".  It seems like a bug caused by the change in the default behaviour of Explorer in Windows 7.  The .Net Framework seemed to operate on the assumption that the path for "My Computer" would never change.  I've filed a bug report here (get over there and upvote it so this can get fixed): https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/757291/environment-getfolderpath-not-working-correctly-in-windows-7#details.  I've updated my post to mention this.

Comment: This only ever worked by accident. The `GetFolderPath` function only gives you the filesystem path to the given special folder - if there's no filesystem path, it returns an empty string. No bug about it, you just expected something that isn't specified by the contract. So not only is your answer no better than Bronto's answer (it relies on non-contractual behaviour just like Bronto's answer does), but in addition, it doesn't work - it only works when your default explorer folder is "My Computer". The same thing applies to "My Documents", but at least that usually exists in the file system :)

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}");
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "::{450d8fba-ad25-11d0-98a8-0800361b1103}");
```

?

Comment: Yes, iexplorer.exe is indeed Internet Explorer while explorer.exe is Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 6):

Try explorer.exe:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}");
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "::{450d8fba-ad25-11d0-98a8-0800361b1103}");
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not work for my Vista:

```
string myComputerPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer", myComputerPath);
```

as Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer returns "" and Process.Start("explorer", "") opens My Documents.

The GUID seems to do it, though:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("...");
```

I know it looks doubtful but just run it. It'll work.  This is the code for my computer. I don't know what it should be for *My Documents*.

Answer (score 0):

> `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("...");`

I know it looks doubtful but just run it. It'll work. This is the code for my computer. I don't know what it should be for My Documents.

On Windows 7 this results in opening the folder from where your executable is running, i.e. the "current" folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had to open MyDocuments and based on comments above I narrowed down the solution to open Explorer without side effects:

```
Process.Start("::{450d8fba-ad25-11d0-98a8-0800361b1103}");
```

I tested it on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score -2):

Samdoss

Just enter the

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(directoryPath);
```

Its very easy. Try that.