# Open Windows Explorer to a Combined-GUID folder

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want, for example, to open the "Font Settings" page. (It's under "Fonts" in the control panel.)

I got its GUID as follows:

```
::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\1\Fonts\::{93412589-74D4-4E4E-AD0E-E0CB621440FD}
```

<sub>I got it using the `URL` of the `NavigateComplete2` event of an `InternetExplorer` interface.</sub>

I tried many different combinations such as:

```
Process.Start("explorer", @"::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\1\Fonts\::{93412589-74D4-4E4E-AD0E-E0CB621440FD}");
```

And:

```
Process.Start("::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}", @"\1\Fonts\::{93412589-74D4-4E4E-AD0E-E0CB621440FD}");
```

But nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried using the [entire string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073999/how-do-i-open-the-my-documents-and-my-computer-folders-from-c) as first parameter?

Comment: Try to change first argument "explorer" with "explorer.exe" in your first combination.

Comment: @ZainAli That isn't necessary - `explorer` _does_ start Windows Explorer, it just doesn't open the required folder. But thanks.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Painfully late answer, but your problem is/was that the url you were using is for some reason not accepted by the shell url handler.

To start that folder you want you can use: `shell:::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\1\::{93412589-74D4-4E4E-AD0E-E0CB621440FD}`. If you really want the font folder to be the parent, try `shell:Fonts\::{93412589-74D4-4E4E-AD0E-E0CB621440FD}`. It gives you the absurd looking path "C:\Windows\Fonts\Font settings"

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what's the general rule here? (or: how did you get that? - How did you know to remove the `Fonts`?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the general rule is that Uou specify A legal heieracy and it works. For example, you can specify just `shell:::{93412589-74D4-4E4E-AD0E-E0CB621440FD}` to have no problem, although it would be odd for that "folder" to lack a parent. You can specify programs and features as `shell:::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\8\::{7B81BE6A-CE2B-4676-A29E-EB907A5126C5}`, or using just the last guid. Change the 8 to a 6 and you get a displa path of `Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Programs and Features`! But the Fonts folder is just weird.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts)));
```

Comment: a) Thanks. But I'm looking for a generic way to use GUID's. b) It doesn't open the fonts **settings** page (You can get to it by clicking on the left on `font settings` on the "fonts" page).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify **Shell** attribute

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer", @"shell:::{93412589-74D4-4E4E-AD0E-E0CB621440FD}");
```

[Source](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/110919-clsid-key-list-windows-7-a.html)