# C# How can I get Process.Start to open an explorer window to the parent of c,d,e etc.)?

Tags: c#

I know I can open directory blah by doing

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\");`

But suppose I want to get the explorer window to the parent of c and list drives c,d,e e.t.c.. How can I do that?   Note `(@"\")` doesn't do it.

i.e. I want

[image]

and not within `C:\` so I don't want

[image]

Comment: see my latest update may it will solve your problem

Comment: @MostafizurRahman yeah but process start info  dot arguments is not as concise as using process.start doing it in one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Try this
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}");
```

Comment: In theory, sure. But it doesn't actually work :) There's no directory path for this particular virtual folder.

Comment: Have you tried Process.Start("explorer.exe", "::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}");

Comment: minus1. Your answer Doesn't work. Try things before you post them. And people should try things before they upvote.

Comment: Change your answer to the one in your comment and i'll accept it

Comment: @Luaan please A)When you comment quote what it is that you're commenting about   B)Can you delete your comment since he fixed his answer and removed the non working thing.

Comment: @barlop chill, people just trying to help you. I don't have time to test every piece of code I post.

Comment: @Mangist fine but know that you are contributing to a database, and expect people to spend their time checking it and downvoting you when you post a wrong answer. Anyhow, you have now got it right and i'll accept your answer.

Comment: @barlop absolutely, it's your problem so take people's suggestions and test them out for yourself. If you really want to nitpick about the rules, you should have searched first and found the many duplicates of the same issue you are asking for. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073999/how-do-i-open-the-my-documents-and-my-computer-folders-from-c

Comment: @barlop I don't see you quoting Mangist when you posted your comment "Doesn't work" :)

Comment: @Luaan great point!  I guess I hadn't since it was clear what I was referring to before his edit. Likewise though your comment it was clear what you were referring to.  So, indeed, v good point.

Comment: @Mangist if you think it was a duplicate then perhaps you shouldn't have answered but should've written a comment to the question linking to the duplicate

Comment: @barlop :) the plot thickens!

Answer (score 2):

`My Computer` is a folder, not a directory. So it doesn't exist in the file system.

However, you can use the folder ID to open it:

```
explorer.exe ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
```

Comment: that works but then there's the question of how to start the process with that argument.   Mangist has commented with a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

This will start `MyComputer`

```
var proc = new Process
 {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
       FileName = "explorer.exe",
       Arguments = "::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}",
    }
 };
proc.Start();
```

Comment: see my latest update this will start parent directory `MyComputer`

Comment: very long winded to use ProcessStartInfo though, since it can be done in one line with Process.Start

Comment: ok no problem I just try to show a solution, you should choose what best